# JButton ActionListener doesn't work (in Eclipse plugin)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

---

### Question resolved:  I mixed up [windowbuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/)'s  quickly test/preview button with eclipse's compile button:

[image]
(only found out by 'accidentally' pausing my mouse on the button and seeing that it doesn't compile)

---

**Original question**

I have a very specific issue:

I have two different classes:

- Class 1 implements a JPanel within a JFrame.
- Class 2 implements a JFrame only.

In Class 2, the following code works perfectly:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class frameTest extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtGeefLiefde;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frameTest frame = new frameTest();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public frameTest() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnTest = new JButton("press");

    btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            testFunction();
        }
    });
    btnTest.setBounds(162, 188, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnTest);

}

public void testFunction()
{
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setBounds(162, 231, 89, 20);
    textPane.setText(":)");
    contentPane.add(textPane);
}

}
```

Now I want to implement the exact same functionality in Class 1 as well.

I tried the following:

```
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    public class frontpanel extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frontpanel frame = new frontpanel();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public frontpanel() {

            JButton btnTest = new JButton("press");

            btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        testFunction();

                   }
            });
            btnTest.setBounds(162, 188, 89, 23);
            panel.add(btnTest);
    }
        public void testFunction()
        { 
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(162, 231, 89, 20);
        textPane.setText(":)");
        panel.add(textPane);
        }
    }
```

where `panel` is the JPanel in the JFrame.

I have been stuck on this for hours. I just can't seem to get ANY `ActionListener` to work. What is causing the problem?

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: your panel is `null` never get initialized, and you never add the panel to the frame

Comment: aditional to @nachokk answer, you haven't add you panel to your frame. you must set its content pane to the panel.

Comment: No that's just copy/paste mistake because my code was very large. Sorry about that. The JFrame does get initialised.

Comment: You should take the time to fix those errors, as when I do and test, as I answered, it works fine.

Comment: They are not errors. I do have the code but my actual Class just has way more code. So I tried to copy only the relevant code but forgot to include the initialisations. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the slighly modified code below to fit my test case of your code, adding `panel` initialition and adding it to `Test` frame, that you mentionned was a copy/paste error, with a dimension for ease of testing, the code works well on my side.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Test extends JFrame {

  private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
          Test frame = new Test();
          frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create the frame.
   */
  public Test() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton btnTest = new JButton("press");

    btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        testFunction();
      }
    });

    btnTest.setBounds(162, 188, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnTest);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    this.add(panel);
  }

  public void testFunction()
  { 
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setBounds(162, 231, 89, 20);
    textPane.setText(":)");
    panel.add(textPane);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I will implement your code and see if it makes any difference. I will keep you updated. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never initialized `panel` and also you have to add to the `jframe`

```
    public FrontPanel() {

                JButton btnTest = new JButton("press");

                btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            testFunction();

                       }
                });
               // btnTest.setBounds(162, 188, 89, 23);  you should avoid using this
                panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(btnTest);
                this.add(panel);
                this.pack();                                                 
        }

}
```

By the way and not less important,

1)Follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) class names starts with UpperCase.

2) Don't extend `JFrame` instead of that use composition against inheritance if you are not overriding `JFrame` behaviour.

Example:

```
public class FrontPanel{

  private JFrame frame;
  private JPanel panel;

}
```

3) Don't use `setBounds` instead of that delegate this job to `LayoutManager`. [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: you don't provide correct example then.. i don't recommend you using `setBounds` , instead delegate that job to LayoutManagers

Comment: try calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()`

Comment: I agree: it was a copy/paste mistake I apologize for. I found your last comment very interesting! I haven't considered `repaint()` yet. I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: revalidate and repaint, call both!!